# How to use laravel array into <script> code for loop(foreach)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to use laravel variables (foreach($attributes as $attribute)) into javascript code

I have dynamic input add or remove the page in laravel blade. visit: [Dynamically Add or Remove input fields using JQuery](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-dynamically-add-or-remove-input-fields-using-jqueryexample.html)

Now I want to use select and dropdown instead of simple input (name) but how to pass variables collection into script tag?

This is first static dropdown:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select class="form-control m-select2" id="m_select2_1" name="attribute[1]['name']">
             <option value="value">name</option>
             <option value="value2">name2</option>
             <option value="value3">name3</option>
         </select>
       </td>
       <td>
           <input type="text" name="attribute[1]['price']" placeholder="Enter your Price" class="form-control name_list" />
       </td>
       <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my code in script tag:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input type="text" name="attribute['+i+'][\'name\']" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="attribute['+i+'][\'price\']" placeholder="Enter your Price" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
});
```

I want to create something like this instead of `attribute[]['name']` in script tag:

```
<select class="form-control m-select2" id="m_select2_1" name="attribute[1]['name']">
    @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        <option value="{{$attribute->id}}">{{$attribute->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: im unsure what your question is. The last code sample is something that should work. If you put your `<script>` tag inside a laravel `viewname.blade.php` file you can even load php code inside your `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Flame I want to use laravel variable in  $('#dynamic_field').append

Comment: if you read my comment that is what I said you could do. You can use `{{ $myVar }}` in your javascript as long as it is in the `blade.php` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@json` or `{!! json_encode() !!}` to assign it to a javascript variable in your `.blade.php` file.

```
<script>
   let data = @json($attributes)
</script>
```

In JS file, `data` variable will have the array you want:

```
console.log(data);
```